# How to remove Irregularity in layout of items in listview in android?

Tags: android, listview

This is how the cart screen looks like. The layout changes as per the length of item name. 
I want to keep a fixed ratio for all columns in the listview and at the same time, keep the size of button fixed.
How to achieve this ?

Below is the Screenshoot and layout code:

[image: Cart Screenshot]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyKxP.png)

Layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:stretchColumns="*"
android:background="#ffffff">
<TableRow>
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/cartlist_layout"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/t1"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/t2"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/t2"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/t2"
    android:id="@+id/t3"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:background="@drawable/delete1" />
</TableRow>>
</TableLayout>
```

Edit1: The Listview layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_mycart">
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView1" />

   <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"

        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/cart" />
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Show the layout code of the `ListView` item.

Comment: Posted the layout code for listview item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `LinearLayout` as root view of the item instead of `TableLayout`. You can add `weights` to the views inside the `LinearLayout`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:id="@+id/t1"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/t2"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/t3"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:background="@drawable/delete1" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Note : You may want to adjust the weights a bit.

Comment: Awesome. Working.

Answer (score 1):

Use *LinearLayout* instead

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/t1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:text="text1"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/t2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:text="text2"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/t3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:text="text3"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

    </LinearLayout>
```